# TapGesture on tableViewCell ContentView

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.6, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a customeized tableviewcell Sub class.

The tableview cell contained UIImgaveView , UIButton and other Controlls.
 I added these in tableViewcell ContentView.

I have to apply  `UITapGestureRecognizer`  on UIImageView .

How can I apply tapGesture to imageview?

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap)];
[tapGR setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tapGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapGR setDelegate:self];
[cell.yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR]; // Your ImageView of contentView
[tapGR release]; //If you aren't using ARC

- (void)onTap
{
    NSLog(@"Image tapped");
}
```

**Note:-** Make sure that you include `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in your header file and user interaction should be enabled for `UIImageView`. 
`yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in your method from where you want to call it..:-

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    [tapOnView setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];//Number of touches Depends on your requirement
    [tapOnView setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];//Number of taps Depends on your requirement
    [tapOnView setDelegate:self];//delegate
    contentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;//Make view userInteractionEnabled,content view is yours image view
    [cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:tapOnView];//Adding TapGesture to view.

 - (IBAction)tap:(id)sender
        {
            NSLog(@"your requirement");//you can perform action here.
     if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIGestureRecognizer self]]) {
        // it's a gesture recognizer.  we can cast it and use it like this
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    } else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton self]]) {
        // it's a button
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    }
    }
```

Enjoy coding..